# Activation Energy of a rotting apple

Tags: energy

A slightly bruised apple will rot extensively in about 3.5 days at room temperature (22.0 degrees Celsius). If it is kept in the refrigerator at 0.5 degrees Celsius, the same extent of rotting takes about 12 days. What is the activation energy for the rotting reaction?

Comment: We do not do your work for you. Rephrase your question so we can guide you on obtaining the answer when you don't understand.

Comment: I have to say, among all the problems I've ever seen, I think this wins top place in the largest stretch of chemical kinetics theory...

Comment: Maybe so, but if such a question seems spurious, it might be quite nice to point out why it is so, and perhaps help the enquirer rephrase it to a question which lends itself to being answered by the theory.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange! Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  Even a rough outline of what you know so far or an educated guess is fine.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. Thanks!